# Could not find toolchain file: conan_toolchain

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, conan

I have a project that uses Conan. It compiles perfectly on macOS and Linux (Ubuntu), but I'm having difficulty compiling it for Windows on GitHub Actions.

The error is as follows:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:154 (message):
  Could not find toolchain file: conan_toolchain
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

However, the file does exist, I made sure of that.

What am I doing wrong?

If you want to see all the logs, just access [this link](https://github.com/carimbo2d/carimbo/actions/runs/6683919967/job/18160632624).

Comment: When building for VS, that is a multi-config environment ``-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`` shouldn't be used at configure time, but ``--config Release`` should be passed at build time (in the command line ``cmake --build . --config Release``, or selecting the configuration in the IDE).

Comment: I think it is the running in the powershell terminal, that is using the `.` as separator. I'd try to quote the ``"conan_toolchain.cmake"`` with double or single quotes.

Comment: @drodri without, I get this error  Please, set the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE variable when calling to CMake adding the
  '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<build_type>' argument.

Comment: @drodri bingo, that was the problem!

Comment: If it is requesting you to add ``-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE``, that shouldn't happen for Visual Studio compiler (and CMake generator). If you want to further check it, it would be worth submitting a Github issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues